# continuous playing playlist

Tags: jwplayer

i've got a jw player with an asx playlist, but it only plays one track at a time, requiring the user to skip to the next track.  any way to make it keep playing with no pauses between tracks?  please let me know.  thanks!

`var so = new SWFObject('mediaplayer/player.swf','wrapper','300','20','2');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','false');
so.addParam("seamlesstabbing","true");
so.addParam('flashvars','file=tracks.xml&autostart=true&loop=true');
so.write('player');`

Comment: Hi Lucas, you question was helpful thanks, but I want to see your SWFObject() function file... can you please help me showing your code. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had to add the **repeat** FlashVar with a value of **list** to a JW Player (v5.9) with an asx playlist today to get the desired playlist functionality you described.

```
var so = new SWFObject('/players/jwPlayer.swf','mediaPlayer','400','320','8'); 
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'true');
so.addParam('wmode', 'transparent');
so.addVariable('repeat', 'list');
so.addVariable('width', '400');
so.addVariable('height', '320');
so.write('player');
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct flashvar parameter is 'repeat' and the correct setting is 'always' for absolute repeating, while the 'list' setting will play each item once and end when the entire playlist has been played.